# Is there a way to serialize a string in java script?

Tags: javascript, file, serialization, cordova

I am new to javascript. I want to store the value of a string in a file. I am able to store the string in a normal text file. But what i need is I want to serialize the data and then store it in a file so that no one can edit it.

Like what we do in java (serialization concept in java).

Can anyone help me in how to serialize a string using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Serialization, usually converts an object into a text format, i.e. Json which then allows you to rebuild the text into an object.

In javascript, you can do this with Json, however storing it in a file would have to be done by server side coding, i.e. via an Ajax request.

Comment: I store the data in a text file using the sample code in http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#File. But my data is stored as a plain text. So that any one can edit and save.But I dont want my text to be editable

Comment: Then `serialization` is not what you want. You want encryption. On javascript this is possible, however it would be flawed as it would only take the attacker to read your javascript to find the key to encrypt/decrypt.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is!

[Serialize data](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

From there you can store it, pass it etc..

Comment: But that is used to serialize form data only right? I need to serialize a simple string. eg: "Hello! how are you" I need to serialize this string.

Comment: serializeArray() is available if you'd like to keep data in arrays.